# keyof doesn't satisfy constraint when nested

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Using the the extension of the keyof of some object type works fine to index that type, but does not work on an extension of the object type. Is there someway to tell TypeScript that the types should work, is this a bug, or am I missing something?

```
type Foo = { bar(a: string): boolean }

// works
type Thing1<F extends keyof Foo> = ReturnType<Foo[F]>

// doesn't work:
type Thing2<Fo extends Foo, F extends keyof Fo> = ReturnType<Fo[F]>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAjAhgJwBRYBcUAzsDgJYB2A5gJTEYIA2EWVUAvgLABQfoSFAAqAC2o0AjAB4YUCAA9gEKgBMSUANYQQcAGawEAPmRQAShGABXHFWHgIshAG0YAXSN8BDkeNoAmJ3klFXVDOAAaWGDlNQ1tXQN4ExQLa1t7SCdXDyA)

ts error:

```
Type 'Fo[F]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'Fo[keyof Fo]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type 'Fo[string] | Fo[number] | Fo[symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
      Type 'Fo[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.(2344)
```

Here is what I'm trying to pull off: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggIhAZgZygXigbwLACgoFQBGAhgF4AUAxgFxTLABOAlgHYDmAlHawK4A2-PAF88eUJCgAhBCnRYoeQsRKMKJOgxYduxAPZ7%20EEq0X5CpRgCZ1PXgFsiERrqIGjJkWNwTos1BjwSKgAZNL%203r5QALIQyMgk7BAAPHgAkADKvERQEAAewBCsACao-gA06bK5BUWlUADWECB6iFARuAB88gAKqiT2EIWMyMlZRADasgC6nRMADNOR4NAAShBg-CCp5gTjNYUlZcGVuGnV%20Yf1TS1tHd0Y68C8jKwAKitj2VNIs975YD0jGAUCoelYDCgbGK%20ToODOjGMxXBWygPzabEazVa7WC0zoAEYRPJMCpGITymSrBSVGRCVBRLg8ACgSCwRCQYgIfIAPJEABWECowAAdDdkBRoflOFASKgKDccf5OBMlkyfCsoONBcLkm8HgpWJc6G8GVAAPTm%20jAEzFKGmRBAqCMPL85DLSSxYAACz0xS%20OUudWOKEpF1qRyxt1xKANSkIsXiiRS4zDSG6QcjvBKSDYEGK6QA-FAKDK0N1tULgMkni93p9xujZp10nQKIMk0k6ImEkkA2nEJ0yxXsjrq7XXh9IAGm50W%20qol7faUdplsgdgzHkKdMnpBhvI4q7sF5Eet3gDfC0oiSMjWKj0fatXuIPiYkNl-2Y-PGXgucgRURYpeCoCAKGScMrlQM8ZGCTp2w-P1kG7RCVwqb9KS5OhZGHLB4wIdlIUGH0-RQkj-Vg0Nv3kBDOwgFC6OSSjt2-XD4WUZRCJBZBRyrOhK11AAiABCQTLygI0CjoETBIZfCOMRZ5XnoXjhXkxllGI5dkAmLlpnkLS-XkxS6ygQzShESlMGEWVUCXJCILgzggA)

Comment: What's wrong with `type Thing2<Fo extends Foo, F extends keyof Foo> = ReturnType<Fo[F]>`? Do you have a scenario that doesn't work in that case?

Comment: I may not understand you correctly, but per the playground demonstration, that doesn't type. TypeScript throws the error.

Comment: Does for me, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAjAhgJwBRYBcUAzsDgJYB2A5gJTEYIA2EWVUAvgLABQfoSFAAqAC2o0AjAB4YUCAA9gEKgBMSUANYQQcAGawEAPmRQAShGABXHFWHgIshAG0YAXSN8BDkeNoAmJ3klFXVDOAAaWGDlNQ1tXQN4OBMUC2tbe0gnVw8gA

Comment: ah, I missed your extra o in Foo.

Comment: My guess is TypeScript doesn't know anything about the possible keys on `Fo`, so it won't let you use it in the second constraint.

Comment: It will let you do this `type Thing2<Fo extends Foo, F extends keyof Fo> = Fo[F]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler has no idea what keys are on something that extends Foo and if they all are functions that have a return type, so if won't let you do it.

Take a look at this example, `Foo` is fine because it has method keys, `Foo2` isn't because it has a non method key, and `Foo3` is okay because it also has all method keys. `Foo2` and `Foo3` are extensions of `Foo`

```
export type Foo = { bar(a: string): boolean; }

export type Foo2 = Foo & { value: string }

export type Foo3 = Foo & { bar2(a: number): string; }

// works
type Thing1<F extends keyof Foo> = ReturnType<Foo[F]>

// error!
type Thing2<F extends keyof Foo2> = ReturnType<Foo2[F]>

// works
type Thing3<F extends keyof Foo3> = ReturnType<Foo3[F]>
```

If you try to type contraint the keys to an extension, you can easily pass `Foo2` and a key on `Foo2` that would not have a `ReturnValue`.

That's the reason why your example is returning a type error.

As I said in the comments, you can constrain your keys to the main type and it will work.

```
type Thing3<Fo extends Foo, F extends keyof Foo> = ReturnType<Fo[F]>
```

However, you can make this work by adding a different constraint that says all the keys on the object with be a method. You don't even need the original type.

```
type Thing<Foo extends Record<Bar, (...args: any) => any>, Bar extends keyof Foo> = ReturnType<Foo[Bar]>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation! added a playground link to the original question illustrating what I'm trying to pull off and where it breaks down

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look and see if I can help.

Comment: wow, I think your last suggestion with the different constraint might be the solution! really neat... would not have come up with that!

Comment: If you are still having problems, let me know what your expected output on your reduce function is and I'll take a look again.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/willium/0e4aa3d24ba52080a2a73e7367519b19

Comment: I'm not sure, template literal types are fairly new, so I'll have to mess around with it.

Comment: I added a comment on how to fix it.